# PHP Search Result page displaying result even after reloading

Tags: php, session

I am customizing the search page of my website. Currently my website is displaying previous search result even after refreshing the page. How can I reset the search on next reload.

My search page code
http://codepad.org/qr9nfvny

Comment: Are you storing Search filter values in `session` ?

Comment: Just looking at your code, you might want to also check [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely because, ***somewhere down the road (in your code) you saved the search string in your session which was not cleared after the search query finished executing.*** If you would **clear the session of the search string** your page would reload without executing the same search as before...